# How to plot 4 rectangles, having their center, and knowing their half width and heigh? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to plot 4 rectangles, I have their center points in a 4X2 Matrix,(A) and I have in a 1X2(B) Matrix the half of width and height. B = [height/2 width/2]; In a for loop.

Comment: Probably with [`rectangle`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
    for i = 1:size(A,1)
     rectangle('Position',[A(i,1)-B(2),A(i,2)-B(1),B(2)*2,B(1)*2]);
     hold on;
     %invert 'Y' if you are plotting inside an image ,  rectangle('Position',[A(i,1)-B(2),A(i,2)+B(1),B(2)*2,B(1)*2]);
    end
```